# PHP If/else/elseif with multiple conditions

Tags: php

Please note, similar questions have been asked multiple times.

**** Though, not this one as far as my search goes! ****

**The goal:**

I need help on how to build a script that shows the page with user settings. It should be based on account level and if the user_id matches with the variable of 'id' in the url. So, basically.. the admin should always be able to see the user settings no matter if the user_id matches the 'id' from the url.

**The problem:**

I can't get it to work with the two variables (user status = 'id' in url, and if the user is admin? Then always show) in a good way, since I don't want to duplicate the "juicy" stuff in two places.

**My current state:**

I'm thinking something like this:

```
#DB:USERS
user_id   user_name   user_level ....
1         ADAM        3 (admin)
2         BRYAN       1 (suspended)
3         CODY        2 (user)
4         DAVID       3 (admin)
```

CODE:

```
<?php
  // Get the logged in user data..
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where user_name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $user_level = $row["user_level"];

  $query... (SELECT * #DB:USERS);..
    $url_id = $_GET['id'];
    $user_id = $row['user_id'];

  if ($url_id == $user_id) {
    #Show all the juicy user setting stuff#
  } else {
    echo 'ACCESS DENIED';
  }
?>
```

So far so good, but how to add the step that says, if the user status is equal to 3 (admin).. then show the jucy stuff anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you know the user viewing the page is an admin? i would expect it to be in a session.

Comment: I think we are missing a variable here.

Comment: You're right! The session ofc. Adding it to the code. But then how? :)

Comment: so why cant you just use ? `if($_SESSION['userLevel]=='3'){...}` t

Comment: Thanks for your reply's guys! I'm not sure if that will do it, since the user should be able to see the "juicy" stuff, if the user id matches the id from the url?

If i go by the suggested solution above, then how to include that part?

Comment: the answer below is correct, just have to adjust whats after the the `or` for your need

Comment: side note, may as well put user level in the session at the same time you put in username, then you dont have to query every time to check it.

Comment: if ($url_id == $user_id || $_SESSION['userLevel]=='3') { may do what you need? || means OR, so at least one conditipn has to apply. Don't know if I understood you correcrly though

Comment: @nikoh You will probably have a bunch of statements in the `if`-block so there is a principle called "fail early" which suggests that you check for all cases which will terminate any further execution of the code first. 
In your case you would invert the condition to `if (!($url_id == $user_id || $_SESSION['userlevel'] == 3)` by using the `!` at the beginning. Then you would move the `echo 'ACCESS DENIED';` statement there and include a `die();` statement. Now you can write all other statements after the one `if` block without the need for any further code block. =>  Increased readability ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question, you need to test if user is admin in addition of the test of user ID, use or condition :

```
// not sure of variable name for userlevel
if ($url_id == $user_id || $_SESSION['userlevel'] == 3) {
    #Show all the juicy user setting stuff#
} else {
    echo 'ACCESS DENIED';
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for your reply!
Well, yeah sort of. Though if the user is not admin, but the user_id matches the url_id.. then the user should be able to see the juicy user settings anyway. Any idéas?

Comment: This condition allows both : user connected who matches $url_id, or admin user.

Comment: " if the user is not admin, but the user_id matches the url_id.. then the user should be able to see the juicy user settings anyway" that's exactly what this does A(matching user) **OR** B(admin)

Comment: That should be what happens. If either the user is admin, OR the 2 ids match, it shows the juicy stuff

Comment: You're great as always guys! Thanks for helping me out and learning me about the operator || = *EITHER*, upvote for u all!